# Post First & Last name from Gmail account to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to post First and Last name from Gmail account to firebase when authentication is done over firebaseAuth.? How to get user profile.?

I'm creating user in firebase over GIDGoogleUser.. and using:

```
let authentication = user.authentication
```

I found on same class something I can probably use, but I need advice is it the right way to do it and how to get First and Last name from it..?

```
let profile = user.profile
```

**My AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
  }
  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken (authentication?.idToken)!,accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in  
        if error != nil {
            return
        } else {
            let registrationReq = FirebaseRegistrationLoginRequests()
            registrationReq.checkIfCreateOrGetUser(user: user!)
        }
    }
  }

  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user:GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {     
    debugPrint(userInfo) 
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.

Add after

```
let authentication = user.authentication
```

this:

```
let fullName = user.profile.name
let firstName = user.profile.givenName
let lastName = user.profile.familyName
```

and than in:

```
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

        debugPrint("fullName:", fullName!)
        debugPrint("firstName:", firstName!)
        debugPrint("lastName:", lastName!)

        if error != nil {
            return
        } else {
            let registrationReq = FirebaseRegistrationLoginRequests()
            registrationReq.checkIfCreateOrGetUser(user: user!)
        }

    }
```

You can also get lot's of other details:

```
             Get the account information you want here from the dictionary
             Possible values are
             "id": "...",
             "email": "...",
             "verified_email": ...,
             "name": "...",
             "given_name": "...",
             "family_name": "...",
             "link": "https://plus.google.com/...",
             "picture": "https://lh5.googleuserco...",
             "gender": "...",
             "locale": "..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Form documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_google_user):

`GIDGoogleUser` has property named `profile` which is kind of class `GIDProfileData`.

`GIDProfileData` has information you need.

Look [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data)